# SQLite iPad performance problems during mass insert and select

Tags: ios, performance, ipad, sqlite

I've been working on an iPad app and all is working fine besides sqlite performance. Now, this app needs to handle a lot of data.

At the moment I'm having 2 issues, one is when I'm populating the database. The current test is 710 records, each with 20 columns and the app can't handle that. This is the main issue, I'm not sure it would ever process anymore than this amount, or even anywhere near this amount but it's what I'm aiming for. My thoughts are; is sqlite even enough to handle this much data, on an iPad.

The second is when pulling data from the database to populate a table view - each row calls for 4 records and the time it takes to call all of these is causing the table to lag slightly whilst it's scrolling. Could I get away with processing the queries in a separate thread? I have tried something similar to this, but I had no luck.

Any help would me amazing, thanks a lot.

Comment: Your second remark about scrolling makes me think it is not an sqlite performance problem. Profile it with the "Time Profiler" instrument and post the functions that use the most time.

Comment: Are the insertions inside a single transaction? 710 rows is nothing, but 710 transactions could easily be a problem.

Comment: I have tried running the Time Profiler but not much seemed to stand out. Did you have any thoughts as to what the issue was?

Comment: I've already attempted to surround my insert queries with BEGIN and COMMIT queries but with no change. Not sure I have them in the right place though, I've never actually used them before and I am using [SQLitePersistentObject](https://github.com/samuraisam/SQLitePersistentObjects) so I'm not sure if that effects the surrounding statements.

Answer (score 0):

In my past project experience, I have seen that index on the tables have slowed down the insert. I dropped the index just before insert bulk, insert the records and recreate the index - I had seen significant difference. Hope this helps